# jQuery on multiple nested fields only working on first

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, coffeescript

I am seeking for some help with jQueries again as I am weak in this area. I have successfully implemented jQuery on my order form to display product:price in a text field whenever product_id is selected via collection_select dropdown menu.

My form is as below:

```
<%= form_for(@order) do |f| %>
.
.
.
<%= f.add_nested_fields_link :single_orders, "Add Product" %>
<%= f.nested_fields_for :single_orders do |builder| %>
  <div class = "form-inline">
    <%= builder.collection_select :product_id, @products, :id, :select_product, {:prompt => "choose product"}, {:class => "product_selection form-control"}  %>
    <%= builder.text_field :ctn_price, placeholder: "Price/carton", id: "ctn_price", readonly: true, class: 'ctn_price_field form-control' %>
    <%= builder.text_field :qty, placeholder: "Quantity",id: "quantity", class: 'form-control' %>
    <%= builder.text_field :price, placeholder: "Amount", id: "amount", readonly: true, class: 'form-control' %>
    <%= builder.remove_nested_fields_link %>
  </div>
<% end %>
.
.
.
<%= f.submit "place order", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

I was able to GET product_prices via jQuery through orders.js.coffee file

```
jQuery ->
  $(".product_selection").on "change", ->
      $.ajax
        url: "/orders/get_product_prices"
        type: "GET"
        dataType: "script"
        data:
          product_id: $('.product_selection option:selected').val()
```

and display it using get_product_prices.js.erb

```
$('.ctn_price_field').val(<%= @product.price %>)
```

everything is working accept that when I add more than 1 nested field, the jQuery seems to be able to only detect the first nested field and only change the first .ctn_price_field what i would like to accomplish is to generate multiple nested field in this same form and able to change each nested_field:price according to the product selected. Thanks in advance!!

Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 0):

You need to run each for that class to access all element associated with same class. Like -

```
$(".product_selection").each(function() {
    // ...
});
```

And make sure this binding is called after your element is bind in HTML.

Or you can use -

```
$('.product_selection').change(function(){
   // code goes here
});
```

Comment: i have implemented your suggestion into my codes but nothing has changed. Is there other solutions? Thanks for your help anyways

Comment: You need to call this function after adding elements in dom.